# How to compare only time(hh:mm:ss) in timestamp field in my sql.?

Tags: mysql

I want to compare only time in timestamp column in mysql like the timestamp column has a value **2016-03-08 01:24:05** and I want to compare it with current time only like **10:13:00**. But the result is always null because it compare current timestamp with old timestamp.

```
select * 
from `user` 
where (startTime >= CURTIME())
```

I want to select all those record which time is greater than current, whatever the date is.. (`startTime` column is `timestamp` type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [TIME_TO_SEC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec). in this query your time convert into second and after then subtract to starttime from current time. and compair it with 0. if result is greater then 0 then its gets all record from table

```
select * from `user` 
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(time(startTime)) - TIME_TO_SEC(time(now()))  > 0 ;
```

Comment: Is `TIME_TO_SEC` always required or is `TIME` enough? `WHERE TIME(startTime) > TIME(now())`

Comment: only TIME is enough